# SpringBoot Kafka -> org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-test-1, groupId=my-test] Node -1 disconnected

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

Small question regarding consuming Kafka messages from a Spring Boot Kafka consumer please.

I am following this well written tutorial (literally just copy pasting the **consumer** part code)

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-kafka

And my code looks like:

```
@Configuration
public class KafkaConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        final Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "kafka-host.com:9093");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "my-test");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        final ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
        return factory;
    }

}
```

```
@Service
public class LoganConsumer {

    @KafkaListener(topics = "the_topic")
    public void listenGroupFoo(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received Message : " + message);
    }

}
```

When I start my application, however, I do see those WARN:

```
2023-01-06T13:15:19.028Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values:

        allow.auto.create.topics = true
        auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
        auto.offset.reset = latest
        bootstrap.servers = [kafka-host.com:9093]
        check.crcs = true
        client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
        client.id = consumer-my-test-1
        client.rack =
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
        enable.auto.commit = false
        exclude.internal.topics = true
        fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
        fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
        fetch.min.bytes = 1
        group.id = my-test
        group.instance.id = null
        heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
        interceptor.classes = []
        internal.leave.group.on.close = true
        internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
        isolation.level = read_uncommitted
        key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
        max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
        max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
        max.poll.records = 500
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor, class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.CooperativeStickyAssignor]
        receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.jaas.config = null
        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
        sasl.login.class = null
        sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
        sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
        sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
        sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
        sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
        sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
        sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
        sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
        security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
        security.providers = null
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        session.timeout.ms = 45000
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
        socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
        ssl.engine.factory.class = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
        ssl.keystore.key = null
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.certificates = null
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

2023-01-06T13:15:19.185Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.3.1
2023-01-06T13:15:19.186Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: e23c59d00e687ff5
2023-01-06T13:15:19.187Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1673010919184
2023-01-06T13:15:19.189Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-test-1, groupId=my-test] Subscribed to topic(s): the_topic
2023-01-06T13:15:19.205Z  INFO 1 --- [           main]  in 2.752 seconds (process running for 3.23)
2023-01-06T13:15:19.966Z  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-test-1, groupId=my-test] Node -1 disconnected.
2023-01-06T13:15:19.968Z  INFO 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-test-1, groupId=my-test] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 1 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 491ms, elapsed time since send: 491ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
2023-01-06T13:15:19.968Z  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#0-0-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-test-1, groupId=my-test] Bootstrap broker kafka-host.com:9093 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
2
```

To avoid confusion, I am not seeing any `Broker may not be available`

But in loop, I am seeing those:

```
 org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-test-1, groupId=my-test] Node -1 disconnected.

 org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Consumer clientId=consumer-my-test-1, groupId=my-test] Cancelled in-flight API_VERSIONS request with correlation id 28 due to node -1 being disconnected (elapsed time since creation: 59ms, elapsed time since send: 59ms, request timeout: 30000ms)
```

Those `Node -1 disconnected.` are quite confusing, especially I am seeing  `Subscribed to topic(s): the_topic`

I am a bit puzzled about what does this mean, and how to fix this please.

Thank you

Comment: Your code seems correct, but this is a network error only you can solve... We don't know what the correct address of your brokers are, or how you need to properly connect to them (authentication, for example? 9092 is the default port, why are you using 9093?) . Does `kafka-console-consumer` work?

Comment: I think that `Subscribed to topic(s):` log INFO message is misleading: it does mean that we really have been connected to Kafka and subscribed. See `KafkaConsumer` source code: it  looks like connection happens only when a `poll()`  is called from the client program.